# Drupal 7 Does "New Node Creation" initiate/prepare the Fields for different Content Types?

Tags: drupal, drupal-fields, drupal-content-types, drupal-nodes

In Drupal 7, i need to `Programmatically` create the Nodes. As usual, there are `Different Fields` set for `Different Content Types`.

For very simple example:

```
Content Type: "car"
Fields: "Model", "Engine", "GearType"

Content Type: "article"
Fields: "Title", "Author", "Media"
```

What i want to be confirmed here is, `while` i am creating a new node, for e.g by using:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = "car";
```

Then..

- Is that (currently creating) new `$node` has been initiated/loaded with its related/corresponded fields, already before get saved?
- To be more clear, if i just suddenly Save a node `node_save($node)` (without filling any other related fields) will that `node` be still having (following) its proper Content Type structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'article';
node_object_prepare($node);
```

There is a nice blog post about this here: http://www.group42.ca/creating_and_updating_nodes_programmatically_in_drupal_7

Comment: Your link is so useful. Thanks :)